# How to remove tkinter - - - - line's when creating menu

Tags: python, tkinter

What is this line and How to remove the lines that appear automatically when creating a menu:

[image: Image of the output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `tearoff=0`. From the [NM Tech Tkinter reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190512165007/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/menu.html):

> tearoff
>
> Normally, a menu can be torn off: the first position (position 0) in the list of choices is occupied by the tear-off element, and the additional choices are added starting at position 1. If you set `tearoff=0`, the menu will not have a tear-off feature, and choices will be added starting at position 0.

You can see the difference in this example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)

tearoff = Menu(menubar, tearoff=1)
tearoff.add_command(label="Tearoff")
menubar.add_cascade(label="Tearoff", menu=tearoff)

notearoff = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
notearoff.add_command(label="No Tearoff")
menubar.add_cascade(label="No Tearoff", menu=notearoff)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `tearoff=False` works too and IMO is much more clear.